# How can I run a script when a specific network interface is up with systemd/networkctl?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I need to run a script when a specific network interface is brought up with systemd/networkctl, i.e. each time it enters state "routable".

- When the interface goes up or down, the device stays "active", i.e. I cannot depend on the "sys-subsystem-net-devices-$DEVICE.device" unit.
- I tried creating a path unit to watch "/sys/class/net/$DEVICE/operstate", but this does not seem to work with the sysfs file system.

Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `networkd-broker` service (or the older `networkd-dispatcher`). It reacts to networkd events through D-Bus and runs shell scripts accordingly.